# web service client in java

Tags: java, web-services

I want to generate a client program using the service

I am unable to display the results, how can I do so?

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException; 


public class searchtry {
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException { 

  SearchRequest request=new SearchRequest(); 
  SearchRequestType1 type1=new SearchRequestType1(); 
  query.setAppId("*********************************"); //Windows Live gave this id for using that service  
  query.setSources(new SourceType[]{SourceType.Web}); 
  query.setQuery("Java"); 
  aratip.setParameters(request); 
  SearchResponseType0 answer= client.search(type1); 
  System.out.println(answer.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: What do you mean, "I can't do it?" What's not working? Be specific.

Comment: What do you mean `you can't do it`? Are you getting an error? Is it returning odd results?  Is it doing nothing? Is it swearing at you and insulting your mother?  Without telling us more we can't really help you.

Comment: "....Is it swearing at you and insulting your mother?" ....I was almost asleep and I am laughing like real bad, with due respect to the OP

Comment: I can't display results.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, calling

```
answer.toString();
```

May or may not result in anything (usually won't).  You might just get a string that represents the instance, not the string you're expecting.  You need to find a method on `SearchResponseType0` that will give you the string representation of the response.  Perhaps a method like `getContent()` or `getResponse()` or something like that but without understanding more about the web service it's difficult to give you more help.  Bottom line, you're using the wrong method to attempt to get the string content of the result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are using the [bing-search-java-sdk](http://code.google.com/p/bing-search-java-sdk/). They have a very nice example on their homepage you might want to look at:

```
BingSearchServiceClientFactory factory = BingSearchServiceClientFactory.newInstance();
BingSearchClient client = factory.createBingSearchClient();

SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.newSearchRequestBuilder();
builder.withAppId(applicationId);
builder.withQuery("msdn blogs");
builder.withSourceType(SourceType.WEB);
builder.withVersion("2.0");
builder.withMarket("en-us");
builder.withAdultOption(AdultOption.MODERATE);
builder.withSearchOption(SearchOption.ENABLE_HIGHLIGHTING);

builder.withWebRequestCount(10L);
builder.withWebRequestOffset(0L);
builder.withWebRequestSearchOption(WebSearchOption.DISABLE_HOST_COLLAPSING);
builder.withWebRequestSearchOption(WebSearchOption.DISABLE_QUERY_ALTERATIONS);

SearchResponse response = client.search(builder.getResult());

for (WebResult result : response.getWeb().getResults()) {
        System.out.println(result.getTitle());
        System.out.println(result.getDescription());
        System.out.println(result.getUrl());
        System.out.println(result.getDateTime());
}
```